# Manually start a Sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

We are trying to achieve the following using Sharepoint:

The user is presented with a form, which they fill out. Upon clicking 'submit', Sharepoint runs a workflow using the inputted information that copies documents to lists, generates reports etc.

We were thinking of achieving this by getting the user to run a site workflow, and presenting the form as a workflow initiation form. The problem we have, however, is that there doesn't seem to be an easy way for getting the user to run the workflow, and be presented with the form.

Is there an easy way to run a specific workflow? I'm aware that the user can view all the site workflows and run them using Site Actions -> view all site content -> site workflows, but this isn't ideal for our user, who only wants to fill out the form and click submit.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, I've spent hours googling and searching this site for info, and this does seem like something that should be easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

So you could catch the event when the user submits the form and then start your workflow from code. To start a workflow, follow this blog article: [Starting SharePoint 2010 Site Workflows from code](http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2009/12/starting-sharepoint-2010-site-workflows.html).

Comment: But this is (1) a link not an answer and (2) about MOSS 2010 **beta**